# How to add bing script code for adding bing search engine to my magento2 website then where to add that script code in Magento2?

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

Do I want to add bing script code for adding bing search engine to my magento2 website then where to add that script code in Magento2?. I don't know how to implement this task. Can you please help me?

Comment: did you get script by bing to add in your site ?

Comment: Hi @ Ansar Husain, yes I have

Comment: admin->content->design->configration->themes(click edit which one current theme) -> HTML head (click) ->  Scripts and Style Sheets (paste js code here)

Comment: Hi @Ansar Husain, I want to add bing search only in the checkout page

Comment: I have added answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for add script only for checkout page.

1. create **registration.php** in app/code/Checkout/BingScript

```
<?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Checkout_BingScript',
        __DIR__
    );
```

2. create **module.xml** in app/code/Checkout/BingScript/etc

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Checkout_BingScript" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

3.Create a checkout_index_index.xml in app/code/Checkout/BingScript/view/frontend/layout

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <script src="Checkout_BingScript::js/bing.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

4. put your js code in app/code/Checkout/BingScript/view/frontend/web/js/bing.js

5. run commands

php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Hi@Ansar Husain, I am trying to in my localhost magento2 I could not find this file path app\design\frontend\Vendor\Themename\Magento_Checkout\layout. This is the my file path C:\xampp7.0\htdocs\magento2test\app\design\frontend\Magento

Comment: That means you did not use any theme yet in your setup

Comment: Hi@Ansar Husain,  I am using default theme

Comment: I have created module for you check it

Comment: Hi@Ansar Husain, I will try and I have created a custom module in my localhost